# Restoring millions of S3 Glacier Deep Archive objects permanently

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with 50 millions of objects in total. 30 millions of these 50 millions objects are stored in Glacier Deep Archive storage class. I need to restore all these 30 millions objects, and then copy them in the same bucket to override the the objects stored in Glacier. I need to copy the files in the same path, keeping the current hierarchy structure.

I have already created an inventory for the 50 millions objects, and I am planning to run a massive restore for all the objects using S3 batch. I have some questions regarding this:

1- if I run the s3 batch to restore the all objects in the inventory manifest (50 millions objects), I suppose it won’t break anything related to the current 20 millions objects already stored in standar class, and it will only apply to the 30 millions objects stored in glacier, right?

2- after restoring the 30 million glacier objects, is possible to run another s3 batch job to override the 30 million objects in glacier with the restored ones?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes and Yes. I suggest you first attempt it on a small batch of objects (eg 100 objects) to see if it behaves as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes objects already restored will succeed with a 200 code. "If the object is previously restored, Amazon S3 returns 200 OK in the response." per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_RestoreObject.html.
2. Yes, you would need to run a batch copy to replace with a storage class in your new desired storage class. Keep in mind that you need to restore the data for long enough for the copy to run.